# How to Delete all Keys in Currently Connected Database in PHP on Certain Condition?

Tags: php, redis

So basically what I want to do is delete all keys from the database if its size is less than 1GB. I want to do it from a PHP script with follwoing code.

```
<?php 

   //Connecting to Redis server
   $redis = new Redis(); 

   $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 

   echo "Connection to server sucessfully"; 

   $redis->select(0);
   $memstats = $redis->info("memory");
   
   if ($memstats["used_memory"] < 8589934592){
   
   $redis->flushAll();
   
   }else{
   
   echo "Mem is less than 1GB";
   
   }

?>
```

I am using `phpredis` for this and just not sure about few things.

- Does this `used_memory` parameters represents current database size?
- Am I doing it right?
- If not then how to get current database size?

Thank you. I do not have much idea of working with Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does this `used_memory` parameters represents current database size?

  To my knowledge, there is no way to know the size of a single database in bytes. However, you can see the size of all databases in bytes using the info command as you did. However, if you only care about the databases' general size, then the required parameter is `used_memory_dataset`. The `used_memory` parameter is for the size of the whole Redis program/instance. Read the [INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info) page for more details.
- Am I doing it right?

  You are doing almost right. **8589934592** is **8 GB**, not **1 GB**. You should define a constant then use it like this:

  ```php
  define( 'ONE_GIGABYTE', 1073741824 );

  if ($memstats["used_memory"] < ONE_GIGABYTE){
    $redis->flushAll();
  } else {
    echo "Mem is NOT less than 1GB";
  }
  ```
- If not then how to get current database size?

  Again, to my knowledge, there is no way to know the size of a single database in bytes. You can see the number of keys in the currently-selected database using the command [DBSIZE](https://redis.io/commands/dbsize) like this: `$count = $redis->dbSize();`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://redis.io/commands/info) to understand the memory stats

The "total_system_memory_human" shows the total amount of memory that the Redis host has. And "used_memory_human" shows the total amount of used memory, which includes data and overhead.

Moreover, I would recommend to set expiry on the keys instead of deleting data based on such conditions.

Comment: According to the Redis manual that you linked above, `total_system_memory_human` is *The total amount of memory that the Redis host has*. It is **not** the total amount of memory available/assigned to Redis.  

Also, `used_memory_human` should not be used in code because it will change depending on the actual used memory. It may be in Kilobytes, Megabytes, or Gigabytes.

Comment: I have edited the text for total_system_memory... Thanks for pointing out the description was not accurate.